# Renderizar un componente u otro dependiendo del estado del componente Footer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Esta ahora mismo es mi App:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NavBar/>
      <PreTest />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Quiero que la function App retorne un componente u otro, dependiendo si el this.state.TestIsOn está a true o false.El estado de esta propiedad lo cambia sólo un botón que está dentro de este componente (`<a><button onClick={this.toggleTest}>Empezar</button></a>`)

Este es el **Footer.js**

```js
class Footer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            TestIsOn: false
        }
        this.toggleTest = this.toggleTest.bind(this);
      }
      toggleTest() {
        this.setState({
          TestIsOn: true
        });
      }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <footer>
                    <div><p class="atajos-p">
                            Ahorra tiempo con los <a href="#">atajos de teclado</a>
                        </p></div>
                    <div class="start-game-container">
                    {!this.state.TestIsOn &&<React.Fragment><p>PRESIONA ENTER PARA </p> <a><button onClick={this.toggleTest}>Empezar</button></a></React.Fragment>}
                    {this.state.TestIsOn &&<React.Fragment><p>PRESIONA ENTER PARA </p> <a><button>Comprobar</button></a></React.Fragment>}
                    </div>
          </footer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

En definitiva, que si `TestIsOn: false` la función App retorne el componente `<PreTest />`, y si `TestIsOn: true` retorne el componente `<Test />` pero nunca los a la vez.

He oído que se pueden pasar "props" pero en este caso no se si eso me serviría, para este caso como puedo "trasladar" el estado de esa propiedad del Footer al de App y hacer lo mismo (un condicional &&) pero en vez de con los botones, con los Componentes. **Tiene sentido esto?**

Actualizo: Cómo ahora hacer que funcionen bien los botones:

```js
return (
            <div>
                <footer>
                    <div><p class="atajos-p">
                            Ahorra tiempo con los <a href="#">atajos de teclado</a>
                        </p></div>
                    <div class="start-game-container">
                    {this.props.handleStateUp &&<React.Fragment><p>PRESIONA ENTER PARA </p> <button onClick={() => this.props.handleStateUp(true)} >Empezar</button></React.Fragment>}
                    {!this.props.handleStateUp &&<React.Fragment><p>PRESIONA ENTER PARA </p>  <button >Comprobar</button></React.Fragment>}
                   
                    </div>
          </footer>
            </div>
        )
```

Todo funciona ahora correctamente salvo que el segundo botón ("Comprobar") nunca aparece.: https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-wildflower-7yqkv?fontsize=14

Comment: Tienes que levantar el estado al componente más cercano.

Comment: Mira la respuesta que te deje, espero que sea de tu ayuda si es así la puedes marcar para que a otra persona le pueda servir en el futuro si se encuentra con tu mismo problema. Saludos !.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LEVANTANDO EL ESTADO**

Se recomienda levantar el estado compartido al al ancestro común más cercano. Para realizar esto un ejemplo claro seria:

App.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'

export default class App extends Component {
    state = { TestIsOn: true }

    handleStateUp = (testInOn) => {
        this.setState({ TestIsOn: testInOn })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <NavBar/>
                {this.state.TestIsOn ? <PreTest /> : <Test />}
                <Footer handleStateUp={this.handleStateUp} />
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Footer.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'

export default class Footer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.handleStateUp(true)} >Enable test</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.handleStateUp(false)} >Disable test</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Esta solución es la que se recomienda en la documentación oficial de React la cúal puedes ingresar para revisar desde [acá](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) y puedes encontrar un ejemplo más real de como implementar el levantamiento de estado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si eso parece que tiene más sentido. Por cierto como puedo conservar la otro función onclick que tenía en el mismo botón (la de toggleTest) ? He probado haciendo esto: onClick={() => { this.props.handleStateUp(true); this.toggleTest;} Pero me da error

Comment: Tu función toggleTest debería estar en tu archivo App.js y pasárselas por props a Footer por ende solo deberías tener una función en el onclick la que te va a actualizar el estado del componente. O necesitas si o si tener dos funciones? si es así ¿Para que?

Comment: Cierto, no lo necesito, pero Necesito tener un condicional si o si que depende de si TestIsOn es false o true, dependiendo si el test ha comenzado el footer renderiza el boton "Empezar" o el botón "Comprobar". Lo he cambiado y ahora me funciona el código pero ahora el botón "Comprobar" nunca aparece... actualizo el código arriba a ver si me puedes ayudar

Comment: Te aconsejo que pruebes mejor con un IF ternario. condición ? true : false

Comment: Nada, funciona perfectamente como lo anterior pero el botón no cambia. No entiendo... el handleStateUp cambia en el momento en el que se clicka el botón, no? Se te ocurre alguna otra opción para realizar esto?

Comment: Puedes subir tu codigo a un repo online para ayudarte de mejor forma? quizás [aca](https://codesandbox.io/)

Comment: Si, gracias aquí te lo paso y lo actualizo al post principal: https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-wildflower-7yqkv?fontsize=14  Si lo pones en pantalla grande verás el botón naranja, pues bien cuando se toca como ves se actualiza correctamente el <Test />  pero el botón también debería ponerse "Comprobar" y no lo hace.

Comment: El error es por que estas evaluando una función como si fuese un true o false... dame unos minutos y te ayudo.

Comment: De hecho te sugiero que abras otra pregunta por que el error que tienes es diferente al problema principal.

Answer (score 1):

ya que el valor la información sobre si el test está o no activo, debe ser reconocida a un nivel más alto en la jerarquía de componentes, guardaría este estado dentro del componente `<App />` y pasaría un callback como prop al componente Footer, permitiendo llamar este callback desde ahí, algo como:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    testIsOn: false
  };

  render() {
    return <div className="App">
      <NavBar/>
      <PreTest />
      {this.state.testIsOn ? <TestIsEnabled /> : <TestIsDisabled />}
      <Footer toggleTestStatus={(testIsOn) => this.setState({...this.state, testIsOn });} />
    </div>;
  }
}

...

class Footer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <button onClick={() => this.props.toggleTestStatus(true)} >Enable test</button>
      <button onClick={() => this.props.toggleTestStatus(false)} >Disable test</button>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

no he probado el código como tal, pero se entiende la idea.

saludos